# Using PDO: fetch vs fetchObject for JSON printout

Tags: php, arrays, object, pdo

I'm using PDO to grab records from a mysql table. The data will be encoded with json_encode() and printed through the Slim framework for the API:

```
$app->get('/get/profile/:id_user', function ($id_user) use ($app) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = :id_user';
    try {
        $stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // THIS!!!
        if($stmt->rowCount()) {
            $app->etag(md5(serialize($data)));
            echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } else {
            $app->notfound();
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

Should I use

```
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or

```
$data = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

? Any direct benefits on fetching the data as an object? I've read some examples but they never explain why. The only usage for the resulting data will be to print it in JSON format. Thanks!

Comment: It's entirely up to you. Do you like to type `$data['colname']` or `$data->colname`?

Comment: In this example I see little difference (both will result in JSONed Object). But there can be a difference if you need to augment the found rows somehow. After a lot of fiddling with JS, I sometimes tend to forget that arrays in PHP have to be passed by reference in this case. ) And yes, `->` syntax is more clean in PHP string literals.

Comment: I think they'll both end up as the same values in JSON, since associative arrays are done as objects in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Though I'd cut an object out with Occam's razor.

Also your code is slightly wrong and redundant. Here is a proper version

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = :id_user';
$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $app->etag(md5(serialize($data)));
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} else {
    $app->notfound();
}
```

- there is no point in setting fetch mode for the every query when you can [set it globally](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).
- numrows() call is also useless.
- and of course catching an exception is redundant, insecure and unreliable.

Comment: thanks for the tips. i've optimized my code. Just one question, though: Why do you say that exception catching is redundant, insecure and unreliable?

Comment: means catching in your case, just to echo error out. It's okay to catch if you want to handle the error itself, not message

Comment: but in this case it is for an API. if the developer receives an error code, he can handle a friendly message for the user in the client app. e.g. "The service is currently down"

Comment: Yes. That's the point. My code has such ability and yours doesn't